# Conditional field in GraphQL Where query

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using Apollo client I am trying to run a query that will return students with any status if the status field is empty. If there is a status filter it should be applied:

```
const statusWhere = inputs.status ? {  equals: $inputs.status  }: {};
query GetStudents($course: ID, $status: String, $statusWhere: status_bool_exp) {
    studentCourses (where :{
        status: {$statusWhere},
        course: {
            id: {
                equals: $course
                }
        },
        # other fields, etc
```

This is giving error:

GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "$".

Could you provide any hints?

Answer (score 1):

But what to do to make it dynamic query, you have to pass the string variable as a query param.

> How will it work conditionally in this case?

Something like this:

```
    query GET_APM_BY_RG($subscriptionName: [String!], $resourceGroupName: [String!], $userAzureId: String!) {
dashboardFilters(
  findoptions: {
    distinct: ["apm"]
    select: { apm: true }
    where: {
      subscription: { 
        subscriptionName : { in: $subscriptionName}
        resourceGroupName: { in: $resourceGroupName } }
      requestors: { some: { requestorId: $userAzureId } }
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of trial and error I was able to figure it out myself. Posting it here because it could be useful for someone else.

**Using the regular JS string interpolation variables works here.**

So you need to define the condition as a string literal:

```
const statusWhere = inputs.status ? 'equals: "'+ inputs.status +'"' : '';
```

Then the whole gpl string looks like this:

```
gql`
          query GetStudents($course: ID) {
            studentCourses (where :{
                status: {
                   ${statusWhere}
                },                      
                course: {
                id: {
                  equals: $course
                }
              },
             
            })
            # fields etc`
```

In this case you **do not need** to pass your string variable as a query param.